# JQuery show/hide elements with matching title and alt tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, title, alt

Is it possible to show an image via mouseover on a link whose only matching tags are title and alt?

My CMS can only generate matching title and alt tags for 2 completely seperated elements. It roughly looks like this:

```
<a href="#" title="aubergine">hover this to show image</a>

<img width="300" height="300" alt="aubergine" src="http://i.imgur.com/0MmkDiI.jpg"></img>
```

I've been able to target the img like so:

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
$('[alt="aubergine"]').css( "opacity", "100" );
});
```

But instead of the specific target `[alt="aubergine"]` i would have to get the image via `[alt="title of this link i just hovered"]`.

Here is a fiddle with the working prototype so far: 
https://jsfiddle.net/82xnqu6j/1/

Comment: The jQuery `.attr()` method is what you would be looking for here.  In addition, you would use `===` conditional checker matching the attributes on hover.  Lastly, to automate the process, you could tie the links and images together via their `.index()` (assuming that it will not change dynamically).  I will try to furbish a working example, but could you provide all the images to be used in your HTML?

Comment: `opacity` goes from `0.0` to `1.0`. It's a fraction, not a percentage, so `100` is not appropriate.

Comment: Well, oops?  Thanks for the hint Barmar. @AlexanderDixon I think i have already found a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery to pull out the `title` attribute of your current element, like in the following live example.

That way you can generalize it for all matching links.

**Live Example:**

```js
$('a').mouseover(function() {
  $('[alt="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"]').css( "opacity", "1" );
});

$('a').mouseout(function() {
  $('[alt="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"]').css( "opacity", "0" );
});
```

```css
img {opacity:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="aubergine">hover this to show image</a>

<img width="100" height="100" alt="aubergine" src="http://i.imgur.com/0MmkDiI.jpg"></img>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/82xnqu6j/4/

Comment: Great solution. Works flawlessly. I have a follow-up question: Is it possible to target the container of our just targeted element? At the moment <img alt="aubergine"> is within a <p> tag that i would also like to change via JQuery. Thanks so much. :)

Comment: Try putting the selected elements in a variable - `var el = $('[alt="' + $(this).attr("title") + '"]');` then `el.css( "opacity", "1" );`, and then you can do whatever else you want with `el`. Also look into using `el.parent()`.

Comment: That works. Amazing. Thanks again, you are awesome. Here is an updated Fiddle if anyone is interested: https://jsfiddle.net/82xnqu6j/8/

Answer (score 0):

Simply try getting the actual title from the link and using it as part of the selector

```
    $('a').mouseover(function() { 
        $('[alt="'+this.title+'"]').css( "opacity", "100" );
    });
```

This applies to any attribute, such as title, src, href, etc.

Check the w3schools page for this in: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `$(this).attr('title')` to choose any attribution of the element in jQuery, same as `this.title` in native JavaScript.

```js
$('a').mouseover(function() {
  $('[alt="' + $(this).attr('title') + '"]').css("opacity", "100");
});

$('a').mouseout(function() {
  $('[alt="' + $(this).attr('title') + '"]').css("opacity", "0");
});
```

```css
img {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" title="aubergine">hover this to show image</a>
<a href="#" title="test">hover this to show image</a>
<img width="300" height="300" alt="aubergine" src="http://i.imgur.com/0MmkDiI.jpg"></img>
<img width="300" height="300" alt="test" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVqLo.png"></img>
```